# Is it possible to call parent class-private methods from child class in Python?

Tags: python, name-mangling

I'm trying to call `__search` from parent class `A` in child class `B` but I get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'B' object has no attribute '_B__search'
```

This seems to be only happening for methods starting with `__`. Is there a way to call these class-private methods when doing inheritance?

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a
        
    def __search(self):        
        return self.a

    def display(self):
        print(self.a)

class B(A):
    def display(self):
        res = self.__search()
        return res

cB = B(2)

cB.display()
```

Comment: By naming the method with two leading (and no trailing) underscores, you are declaring that it is a private method that cannot be accessed by child classes.  Why did you do that if you want to access it from child classes?

Comment: Well it's more like trying to patch someones code for the short term while I can find better solution

Comment: For the sake of nomenclature, `__search` isn't a dunder method since it doesn't have underscores on both sides.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, but it's terrible practice.

In Python, a method whose name begins with `__` and does not end with it (so magic methods like `__add__` are excluded) is obfuscated with the class name. That is,

```
class A:
  def __foo(self):
    return 1
```

is equivalent to

```
class A:
  def _A__foo(self):
    return 1
```

So if you *really* want to call `__search` defined on `A`, you should write

```
res = self._A__search()
```

Again, this is bad practice. Methods starting with `__` are obfuscated *because* that's the Python convention for private functions, so they *shouldn't* be called from outside the class or in subclasses. You mention in the comments that this is a temporary fix, so that's understandable, but I do hope it's not intended to stay this way for very long.

Answer (score 2):

An attribute name beginning with `__` is private, and mangled to `_classname__attribute`. You need to call it by the mangled name.

```
class B(A):
    def display(self):
        res = self._A__search()
        return res
```